# Is there a way to stack multiple 2D (numpy) image arrays about a specified point?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, image, numpy

I need to stack many images that are represented by 2D numpy arrays of the same shape (i.e., take the sum or the median of them all). However, as I stack them, they need to be aligned properly -- each image, while the same shape, is all black with a small circular object around the center, but not exactly at the center. I can find the coordinates of the centroid for each image (using the module `SourceProperties.centroid` through the package `photutils`), but these coordinates will be different for each image -- they are also subpixel coordinates (example: `(y, x) = (203.018, 207.397)`).

I do not know of a way to simply move the objects to the center of the arrays, given the centroids have subpixel coordinates, so it seems like it would be more straightforward if there was a way to align each one by their unique centroid coordinates as I stack them... in other words:

```
import numpy as np
# First image = array1, shape = (400, 400)
centroid1 = (203.018, 207.397)

# Second image = array2, shape = (400, 400)
centroid2 = (205.256, 199.312)

array_list = [array1, array2]
>>> stacked = np.median(array_list, axis=0) # but while setting centroid1 = centroid2 so that the two centroid points exactly overlap while computing median
```

But I'm not really sure how this would look in code. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: ignore the subpixel/fractional part, as it makes no sense for arrays. An array cannot be shifted by `0.34` elements to the right.
Step 2: roll arrays to place the centroids consistently.
Step 3: stack them.

As illustrated by the code below, which places centroids in the geometric center of the array.

```
centroid1 = (203.018, 207.397)
centroid2 = (205.256, 199.312)
centroid1 = np.round(centroid1).astype(np.int) 
centroid2 = np.round(centroid2).astype(np.int) 
center = np.array(array1.shape)//2
array1_rolled = np.roll(array1, center-centroid1, (0, 1))
array2_rolled = np.roll(array2, center-centroid2, (0, 1))
array_list = [array1_rolled, array2_rolled]
stacked = np.median(array_list, axis=0)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking for a way that does take into account the subpixel parts, and centers it there exactly before stacking. Maybe oversampling multiple times would do the trick?

Comment: Try [`scipy.ndimage.zoom`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.zoom.html) to magnify the images: magnifying by the factor of 10 makes 0.1 pixels 1 element of array, etc.